# Thunderbird 78 on Windows stopped working (getting email) with my Ubuntu 18.04 Postfix/courier (sending still works)

Tags: server, thunderbird, postfix

One of my customers just upgraded his Thunderbird installation to go to the latest version which at this time is 78.4.0. Since then he can't access my Postfix mail server to view his messages. However, it works perfectly in all other cases.

When looking at the logs that courier generates, I can see a LOGIN immediately followed by a LOGOUT. When I try to setup a new Thunderbird under Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e. version 68) it works like a charm. Absolutely no problem.

I've read about the [TLS version 1.2 being mandatory](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-78-faq#w_after-upgrading-to-thunderbird-78-i-cannot-get-or-send-email-messages). I tested with [Check TLS](https://www.checktls.com/TestReceiver) and it clearly says TLS 1.2 (see picture). So I'm not too sure what else would have changed that it doesn't want to properly connect. Also no errors are reported on either side, which is the strangest part. At least one side should know what's going on...

Any idea what else could be wrong? Would Thunderbird check whether the TLS is mandatory and if not generate an error and quit?

[image]